# Sort Posts Alphabetically by Multiple Categories

Tags: posts, sort, array

Basically I have an array of posts which I want to sort by title.

```
$categories = get_categories('child_of=4'); 
$arr_records = array();
$post_data = array();

foreach($categories as $category) 
{
    $sub_catname = $category->cat_name;
    foreach(get_posts('cat='.$category->term_id) as $post) 
    {
        $arr_records[] = $post_id;
        $post_data[] = $post;
    }
}

foreach($post_data as $show_post)
{
     echo $show_post;
}
```

How do I sort the `$post_data` array?

Comment: Please also take a look at the linked post by scribu and Mike Schinkels code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `orderby` and `order` parameters in the argument list. See the [Orderby_Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) section of WP_Query for details.

```
$category_ids = $arr_records = $post_data = array();

$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=4' );
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $category_ids[] = $category->term_id;
}

$post_data = get_posts( array(
    'cat'     => $category_ids,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
) );
```

`$post_data` should now be sorted by post title [A-Z].

Comment: Hi This doesn't work. I want to sort the $post_data[] array by title and display

Comment: See the the edit.